# Access generic outer class field from inner class without casting

Tags: java, generics, casting, inner-classes

This is the code:

```
public class OuterClass<T> {
    private T outerField;

    public class InnerClass<T> {
        private T innerField;
        public void setField() {
            innerField = (T) outerField;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write 'innerField = outerField' avoiding a cast to T?

I feel like this is not the correct way to access a generic outer class field because the inner class is supposed to know the type of the outer field.

EDIT:
I tried your suggestion and it worked in that sample of code that I posted.
But my real code is something like this:

```
public class OuterClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>  {
    private T outerField;

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

    public class InnerClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<T> {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            T innerField = (T) outerField;
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void remove() {

        }
    }

}
```

Again, how can I write 'innerField = outerField' avoiding a cast to T?
Sorry, for the double question, but I tried to write the smallest code snippet possible (and it did not comprise my real problem).

The point is that I can not remove the type parameter T from the inner class here because I have to state that it must implement Iterator.

Comment: Seems to me that `T` for `InnerClass` might be hiding `T` from `OuterClass`. Remove the type parameter from `InnerClass` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, but my real problem is a little more complex. I edited my question.

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing for your actual code? Seriously, try it. Keep `<T>` on the `implements Iterator<T>`, but remove the part on `InnerClass`.

Comment: I actually solved my problem now. I should just write 'implements Iterator<T>' in the inner class without recreating a new parameter T (that would shadow the outer one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the type parameter from InnerClas works as @user3580294 has suggested. So the following compiles without any errors.

```
public class OuterClass<T> {
    private T outerField;

    public class InnerClass {
        private T innerField;
        public void setField() {
            innerField =  outerField;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InnerClass#innerField` is not necessary of the same type as `OuterClass#outerField`, since the inner `T` parameter is hiding the outer one.